# Why isn't the in-memory repository reset in different requests when the service is registered as transient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am attempting to understand the meaning of `AddTransient` method. I created an asp.net webapi, the complete project can be seen [here](https://github.com/pstricks-fans/testing).

Let me quote the main code here:

```
public class StudentService : IStudentService
{
    private static List<Student> students = new List<Student>
    {
        new Student{Id=1,Name="Andy"},
        new Student{Id=2,Name="Bobby"}
    };


    public List<Student> Create(Student student)
    {
        students.Add(student);
        return students;
    }

    public List<Student> GetAll()
    {
        return students;
    }
}
```

and

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class StudentController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IStudentService iss;

    public StudentController(IStudentService iss)
    {
        this.iss = iss;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<Student>> GetAll()
    {
        return Ok(iss.GetAll());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<List<Student>> Create(Student student)
    {
        iss.Create(student);
        return Ok(iss.GetAll());
    }
}
```

In my understanding, because the service is registered as transient, every request should reset the `students` field to a list of 2 `Student`.
In other words, every creation of new `Student` by sending POST request, the server should response with a list of only 3 `Student`.

But it turns out, the number of `Student` in the response becomes larger and larger if I do multiple creation.

## Question

Why isn't the in-memory repository reset in different requests when the service is registered as transient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `students` field is static.

Yes, transient service class is instantiated each time, but in your case, every instance uses the same stafic field.

Just remove fhe static modifier and it will work as expected.

Comment: May I ask a relevant question? If I remove the`static` and change to `AddScoped` (instead of `AddTransient`), why is the in-memory reset on every HTTP request? Is it because a new instance of the controller is created per request?

Comment: `Is it because a new instance of the controller is created per request?` Yes.